# Rails routing - Passing unique id into url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have the following in a view:

```
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
<% @people.each do |person| %>
<dt> <%= person[:name] %> </dt>
<dd> <%= button_to('Check', person_check_path, :class => 'btn btn-medium btn-primary', :method => :get)  %>
<% end %>
```

The url represented by this view is: `www.website.com/{town_id}/person/`

`person_check_path` looks like this:

`www.website.com/{town_id}/person/{person.id}/check`

My question is how can I pass `person.id` into the `person_check_path` dynamically? Right now the above button links to the same url everytime, but I need it to change based on which person the button is clicked for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should add the new get request in the routes, something like that:

```
get "/:town_id/person/:person_id/check" => "town#check", :as => :check_town_with_person
```

Then you can call the route from anywhere, for example:

```
link_to "My Link", check_town_with_person_path(:town_id => @town.id, :person_id => @person.id)
```

Remember that these fields (setted in the routes) are mandatory. You can even add some not mandatory params in this manner:

```
 link_to "My Link", check_town_with_person_path(:town_id => @town.id, :person_id => @person.id, :another_var => "my_var")
=> /3/person/1/check?another_var=my_var
```

Comment: Ah, score. The second piece of that where you pass the parameters in is what I was missing. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Place the params you would like to send in the brackets of the path variable. That's all ;)